# Why does second function not wait until first (async) function has finished to fire? (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

What do I need to do to make `doSomethingWithItems()` wait until after `fetchItems()` has completed?

```
const [items, setItems] = useState();

const fetchItems = async () => {
  try {
    let responseData = await sendRequest(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/items/user/${userId}`);
    setItems(responseData.items);
  } catch (err) {}
};

const doSomethingWithItems = () => {
  const filteredItems = items.filter(x => x.title === 'something');
  setItems(filteredItems);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchItems(); // ** WAIT FOR THIS TO FINISH BEFORE MOVING ON **
  doSomethingWithItems();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `fetchItems` is `async`, it returns a `Promise`.  Which you can follow with `.then()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchItems().then(doSomethingWithItems);
}, []);
```

Or, more expanded syntax to better understand the structure:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchItems().then(() => {
    doSomethingWithItems();
  });
}, []);
```

**However**, your next problem is tracking state.  Note that `doSomethingWithItems` depends on `items`.  But [state is not updated immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/328193).  Instead of updating state in `fetchItems`, return the new value and pass it to `doSomethingWithItems`:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState();

const fetchItems = async () => {
  try {
    let responseData = await sendRequest(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/items/user/${userId}`);
    return responseData.items;
  } catch (err) {
    // You probably want to do something meaningful here
    // At least return something:
    return [];
  }
};

const doSomethingWithItems = (newItems) => {
  const filteredItems = newItems.filter(x => x.title === 'something');
  setItems(filteredItems);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchItems().then(newItems => {
    doSomethingWithItems(newItems);
  });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
   (async()=>{
      await fetchItems(); 
      doSomethingWithItems();
   })();
}, []);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

React documents that if you are calling asynchronous code from within a `useEffect()` that you are best to define an `async` function INSIDE the `useEffect()` and then call that function.  This is what [yah yaha's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14530075/yah-yaha) solution is doing, though because it uses the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) approach, it might not be obvious as:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const doMyAsyncStuff = () => {
    await fetchItems();
    doSomethingWithItems();
  }

  doMyAsyncStuff();
}, [....]);
```

However, as [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) answer hints at: the next problem is that the "set state function" of `useState()` is asynchronous but it does not return a Promise.  So this means that your code cannot `await` it or `.then()` it.  You have NO WAY of knowing when the call to `setItems()` will actually finish...you cannot wait for it.

Good news!  React has a solution for that -- React will RE-RENDER a component after its state gets updated by the "set state function".

And as David suggests, you can have React do something in (react)ion to a specific state variable being modified with use of a `useEffect()` -- "when the `items` state variable has a new value, here's some code I want to run".

React is a pretty simple system overall.  But it takes a bit of wrapping your head around state variables, rendering, and JavaScript's asynchronous code execution.

I strongly encourage all of my friends (and make it a requirement of all of my coworkers) to watch the video [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=1s) multiple times.  Especially the parts about Synchronous and Asynchronous code execution (time links are in the video description).